# Can't GUI login after nvidia update

Tags: nvidia, graphics

My Ubuntu 16.04 system was running OK until I allowed today's update.  After the system reboot, I am not able to log in using GUI.  After entering in my password, the system will pause, then after a bit the screen will go black, and then return to the login screen.  One of the updates was an nvidia driver update `nvidia-current:amd64` (304.131-0ubuntu3, 304.132-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) from  `/var/log/apt/history.log`

When I remove the nvidia using

```
$ sudo apt purge nvidia-*
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  nvidia-304* nvidia-common* nvidia-current* nvidia-opencl-icd-304*
  nvidia-settings*
```

the system works, although I think this is using base graphics.  When I reinstall using

```
$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings
The following additional packages will be installed:
  nvidia-304 nvidia-opencl-icd-304
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nvidia-304 nvidia-current nvidia-opencl-icd-304 nvidia-settings
```

the system no longer logs in and is bad as before.

Some system info:

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G98 [Quadro NVS 420] (rev a1)

$ ls -latr .Xauthority
-rw------- 1 gallagherlab gallagherlab 86 Nov  4 14:25 .Xauthority
```

below did not change anything, bad permissions persist after reboot

```
rm .Xauthority 
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER $HOME 
chmod +x -R $HOME
```

I tried to install back to 304.131-0ubuntu3 using `.run` file but ran into X issues.

Any help to get this fixed would be appreciated.

Comment: Nvidia says the required driver for your card is 340, not 304: http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/107868/en-us

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Comment: Many thanks to all commenters, especially @CelticWarrior.  It is notable that the nvidia driver version that I had worked fine for years but I installed 340 since that seemed to be correct.  Install worked after dealing with X server issues helped by link of Fabby. System is now good.  What I did listed below in case it is helpful.
sudo service lightdm stop
sudo update-initramfs -u
#reboot
sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-340.98.run

Answer (score 0):

Reported/Confirmed as Bug #1639180. I had the same problem and ended up manually installing Nvidia-304.131 Note that you have to first install the MTRR patch to the Nvidia .run file (fairly easy to do ... instructions and the patch file can be found on-line).